# what Django request.META is

Tags: python, django, django-views

I read a lot of articles about `request.META` but I didn't understand anything about it and what it does.
Can anyone explain it?

Comment: How about the official docs? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

Answer (score 8):

**request.META** contains all the metadata of the HTTP request that is coming to your Django server, it can contain the user agent, ip address, content type, and so on.

Please read the official docs before asking for something in here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META